# Configure webpack to use custom require function

Tags: webpack

Is there any way to use custom require functions in webpack? So that instead of the standard ways to require a module

```
const styles = require("styles.css");
import styles from "styles.css";
```

I could write something like this

```
const styles = loadStyles("styles.css");
```

where `loadStyles` is a non-existing function but webpack would handle it in the same way as `require`.

This would be super-handy for running unit tests in node. For obvious reasons node cannot load a CSS or any other resource file with `require` as `require` is only for javascript modules. But it's pretty straightforward to mock a custom global function just for unit tests:

```
function loadStyles() { return "fake styles"; }
```

Long story short, I want to be able to tell webpack that `loadStyles` (or any other function) is the new `require`.

Comment: Maybe an alias would work, like `const loadSomething = require;`, then `const something = loadSomething('module_ref')`.

Comment: Hmm, no. No matter how you name it, it is the same old `require` function, so calling it in node to load a CSS file still would fail.
I want to be able to tell webpack that `loadStyles` is the new `require`.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't - not without using loaders. [Resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve) only allows you to change the resolvement of pathes, not the loading by itself which means you can't replace/change the loaded content.

You can use Babel which allows skipping such imports. For React, there even exists a whole package for doing this: [Babel-Plugin-React-CSS-Modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-css-modules). This package allows including and resolving stylenames but keep the stylesheet separate of your script while testing/server side rendering.

If you're using Jest, it has a separate section on [Handling Static Assets](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#handling-static-assets).

---

In general it depends on what you want to achieve. Many frameworks - or webpack/babel configurations at least - depend on imported style names (often hashed or something like that). This means you need the resolved class names of your stylesheets inside your scripts. Otherwise you won't be able to run conditions and other algorithms on them.

Babel and other applications/libraries allow you exactly that. They resolve your `scss` or `css` stylesheets by using `import` or `require` and look which classes are inside the stylesheet to map it into an object inside javascript. They don't pay attention to the stylesheets afterwards. This makes it perfect for tests and server side rendering as classes are resolved but handled by a different webpack loader.

There is no further need of a separate `loadStyles` function, which might do exactly that, except if you load styles from remote. To my knowledge, webpack doesn't support this at the moment (but loaders might help out here, too).

If you really want to do a lot of non common changes to your stylesheets, stick to `require`, write your own loader for it and activate/deactivate the loader based on an `ENV` parameter (e.g. `production | test | development`).

Comment: So I need to write a JS loader which takes the original file content, parses it, finds the occurrences of 'loadStyles', replaces them with 'require', and gives the result back to webpack?
Or a Babel plugin which does the same?

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. Don't create a new function which does exactly the same thing as `require` if you're backed by the availabilty of webpack loaders. It would make your code just hard to maintain.

Comment: The most straightforward implementation of `loadStyles` for tests is to return a `Proxy` object which simply returns names of the called methods, or something like this, so I don't need any webpack loaders to make tests work. 
In fact, I want to _avoid_ using webpack in tests.
I have no idea how to override the standard `require` function from node to make it able to load images, styles, etc instead of javascript modules.